# How to hide the exporting of some symbols in CMake while linking a C++ shared library for AIX platform

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, shared-libraries, xlc

I am building a shared library on AIX using XLC compiler which depends on a static library.  The issue am facing is the shared library built is exporting some of the symbols of the static libary which should be hidden. I noticed that, in the linker command if I directly specify the library instead of using  -L <path_to_lib> -l then the symbols are exported as expected, But if I link like  ../../some_path/libxyz.a then it exports many symbols when most of them should be hidden.

With the below command the libabc.so exports some of the symbols of libxyz.a which should be hidden

```
/usr/bin/xlC_r -q64 -qthreaded -qhalt=s -O -DNDEBUG -Wl,-brtl -G -Wl,-bnoipath -o abc.so <path>/abc.cpp.o <path-to-lib>/libxyz.a
```

With the below command the symbols stay hidden as expected

```
/usr/bin/xlC_r -q64 -qthreaded -qhalt=s -O -DNDEBUG -Wl,-brtl -G -Wl,-bnoipath -o abc.so <path>/abc.cpp.o -L<path-to-lib> -lxyz
```

I have two questions here

1. What is the difference when we link the file directly as "/libxyz.a" vs when we link as "-L  -l"
2. My CMakeLists.txt looks like the following.

   add_library(abc SHARED src/abc.cpp)

   target_link_options(abc )

   target_link_libraries( abc PRIVATE xyz::xyz)

Here abc is the file shared library that am building and xyz::xyz is cmake target for libxyz.a which is a dependency.

With these Cmake rules the linker command expands to

```
 /usr/bin/xlC_r -q64 -qthreaded -qhalt=s -O -DNDEBUG -Wl,-brtl -G -Wl,-bnoipath -o abc.so <path>/abc.cpp.o <path-to-lib>/libxyz.a
```

How to Achieve this kind of linking using Cmake

```
/usr/bin/xlC_r -q64 -qthreaded -qhalt=s -O -DNDEBUG -Wl,-brtl -G -Wl,-bnoipath -o abc.so <path>/abc.cpp.o -L<path-to-lib> -lxyz
```

Comment: A static library is really nothing more than an archive of object files. Linking with a static library is equivalent to link with the individual object files of the static library. Therefore the "rules" for your library and its own object files (and the symbols "exported" by it) also applies to the static library linked to your shared library.

Comment: with GNU `ld` you could do `--exclude-libs libxyz.a`, maybe your linker has something similar

Comment: You could try using `make` and `libtool` instead of `cmake`. See also this: http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/aix-linking.html#Q0017

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond That's just about a different way to *build* libraries, and is unrelated to "exported" symbols from the built library.